Excepción producida en 0x0000000000000000 en Project.exe: 0xC0000005: Infracción de acceso al ejecutar la ubicación 0x0000000000000000
Me sale un error mientras se ejecuta mi código, después de la línea glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

Error: Excepción producida en 0x0000000000000000 en Project.exe:
0xC0000005: Infracción de acceso al ejecutar la ubicación
0x0000000000000000.

Estoy usando Visual Studio 2022.
#define GLFW_INCLUDE_NONE
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <glad/glad.h>
#include <iostream>


int main(void)
{
    GLFWwindow* window;

    /* Initialize the library */
    if (!glfwInit())
        return -1;

    /* Create a windowed mode window and its OpenGL context */
    window = glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, "Hello World", NULL, NULL);
    if (!window)
    {
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }

    /* Make the window's context current */
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    /* Loop until the user closes the window */
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        /* Render here */
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        /* Swap front and back buffers */
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);

        /* Poll for and process events */
        glfwPollEvents();
    }
    introducir el código aquí
    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}


Le estás diciendo a GLFW que no cargue las funciones de OpenGL para que GLAD se encargue.
#define GLFW_INCLUDE_NONE

El problema es que en tu código nunca haces la debida inicialización de GLAD. Entonces, al momento de llamar la API ninguna función se encuentra cargada.
Debes inicializar GLAD inmediatamente después de establecer el contexto de OpenGL y antes de hacer cualquier llamada a la API.
La inicialización la puedes hacer con     gladLoadGL(glfwGetProcAddress).
glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

int version = gladLoadGL(glfwGetProcAddress);

Para más información, mira los ejemplos del repositorio y la documentación.
